# UnsupportedOperationException in AbstractList.remove() when operating on ArrayList

Tags: java, list, iterator, arraylist

`ArrayList`'s list iterator does implement the remove method, however, I get the following  exception thrown:

```
UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:144)
```

By this code:

```
protected void removeZeroLengthStringsFrom(List<String> stringList)
{
    ListIterator<String> iter = stringList.listIterator();
    String s;
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        s = iter.next();
        if (s.length() == 0)
        {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? I have verified that the `List<String>` I am passing in are indeed `ArrayList<String>`.

Thanks!

Comment: is more than one thread operating on the same `List<String>`?

Comment: I suggest you verify that the runtime type of `stringList` is _really_ of type java.util.ArrayList.  I suspect you may have either a `Vector` or `Stack` or an `ArrayList` from some different package that does not override `remove(int)`.

Comment: How did you verify it?  Did you directly examine `stringList.getClass()` within `removeZeroLengthStringsFrom()`, etc.?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I think you may be using the `Arrays` utility to get the `List` that you pass into that method.  The object is indeed of type `ArrayList`, but it's `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, not `java.util.ArrayList`.

The `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` version is immutable and its `remove()` method is not overridden.  As such, it defers to the `AbstractList` implementation of `remove()`, which throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: what's the  solution for that?!!

Comment: Solution would be something like this: new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))

Comment: There are two possible solutions.  The first, as Kong implied, is to make a copy of the immutable ArrayList and pass that in.  The second, and preferable (in my opinion), solution is to rewrite `remove...` to return a List and construct a new mutable List in the method, returning it to the caller.  That solution won't always be plausible (for example, if you're hooked into a framework that you can't modify), but O(n) (iterate) is slightly better than O(2n) (copy then iterate).

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you are being passed an ArrayList, as the remove method on the ArrayList iterator does not throw that exception.

I'm guessing your are being passed a user derived class of ArrayList who's iterator does throw that exception on remove.

```
public void remove() {
    if (lastRet == -1)
    throw new IllegalStateException();
        checkForComodification();

    try {
    AbstractList.this.remove(lastRet);
    if (lastRet < cursor)
        cursor--;
    lastRet = -1;
    expectedModCount = modCount;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```